# Set a calculated property value dynamically

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic3

I have a form like below. Can you tell me how to fill the calculate field value (`contingency`) dynamically when the user changes the value of `budget1` and `budget2` properties? I have tried many ways no luck yet :(

*.html*

```
    <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="createOrUpdate(form)" novalidate>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" formControlName="budget1" [(ngModel)]="project.budget1"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
         <ion-input type="number" formControlName="budget2" [(ngModel)]="project.budget2"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
       <ion-item>
       <ion-input type="text" formControlName="contingency" [(ngModel)]="project.contingency" disabled></ion-input>
       </ion-item>
   </form>
```

*model.ts*

```
export class ProjectDetail {
    budget1: number;
    budget2: number;
    contingency: number;
 }
```

.ts

```
export class ProjectComponent {

  @Input() data: any;
  @Output() onSelectProject: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();
  form: FormGroup; project: ProjectDetail = new ProjectDetail();

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {
    this.initForm();
  }

  //init Form
  initForm() {
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      budget1: ['', Validators.required],
      budget2: ['', Validators.required],
      contingency: [{ value: 0, disabled: true }],
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: use ngModelChange for both fields

Comment: Hope you show how to do that? @Sajeetharan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **`ngModelChange`** and pass the values to a function and then calculate them inside the function,

```
 <ion-item>
          <ion-input type="text" (ngModelChange)="calculateContingency()" formControlName="budget1" [(ngModel)]="project.budget1"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
         <ion-input type="number" (ngModelChange)="calculateContingency()" formControlName="budget2" [(ngModel)]="project.budget2"></ion-input>
        </ion-item>
 <ion-item>
```

and in **`TS`**

```
calculateContingency(){
   this.contingency = this.project.budget2 + this.project.budget1;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works. But can you tell me how to avoid `NaN` value which shows on the `contingency` filed on the template? Hope I have initialized it correctly no?

Comment: you need to cast it to int or declare the value as 0 initially. mark if it helped

Comment: glad to help bro !